# ETL Tool suggestion for REST input and ODATA (or REST) output

Tags: database, rest, odata, etl, erp

We have a REST Data source and need to go to an ERP ODATA destination.

Data is tabular, mostly strings, numeric and simple types.
Not a lot of data (less than 1,000 rows each day).

We would like a ETL tool with the following features:

1. Logging
2. Command line friendly
3. Automated nightly operation (scheduled runs)
4. Simple GUI (we may have to do some simple transformations or filtering)
5. Alert (email) for errors
6. Fairly easy to learn (we have some NiFi gurus, but that might be too much)
7. We don't care if it is not Free or Open Source, in fact paid support is better
8. Not a cloud service. The data sources are local to the company network. Data cannot go offsite.

Google searchers for this level of detail have not been that successful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what is the use case of command line?

Some of the top ETL tools are:

- [Nifi](https://nifi.apache.org/)
- [Pentaho](https://www.hitachivantara.com/en-us/products/big-data-integration-analytics/pentaho-data-integration.html)
- UC4
- [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/)

If you don't have a lot of data some CI tools such as Jenkins and TeamCity might actually be enough. But you would have to write the script yourself

Comment: So you mean a SDK or API, ETL is not easy to test since it is at Integration level you will need to simulate all the components.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have a look into Informatica Powercenter. Its a paid tool and the support is fairly good.

Logging  - provides a lots of way to log the process

Command line friendly - good command line tools available can be called through any CI /CD tools

Automated nightly operation (scheduled runs) - Tool offers inbuilt scheduler for use and supports complex schedulers as well with help of command line

Simple GUI (we may have to do some simple transformations or filtering) - GUI is fairly easy and lots of tutorials available on youtube for this tool

Alert (email) for errors - You can enable the email error with simple command / drag-drop functionlaity or make use of backend command line

Fairly easy to learn (we have some NiFi gurus, but that might be too much) - This is subjective but this tool is fairly simpler.

We don't care if it is not Free or Open Source, in fact paid support is better - This is a paid tool

Not a cloud service. The data sources are local to the company network. Data cannot go offsite-- best part of the tool. available on both on-premise as well on cloud. Your choice of selection.

Comment: Also rest api calls are supported.